# Android push Notification through firebase (server side)

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, php-curl

I am trying to send push notification to my android device from server using firebase cloud messaging system. I was able to successfully register my device and token for my device was generated as well. I am having trouble sending notification to my device using the below script

```
<?php

function send_notification($token1,$message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array('registration_ids'=>$token1,'data'=>$message);
    $header = array('Authorization:key = <my key here>','Content-Type: application/json');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result===false)
    {
        die('Curl failed'.curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}

require "init.php"; //my db details here

$sql = "select token from fbuser";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$tokens = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $tokens[] = $row["token"];   // i was able to successfully echo out token as well
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

$message = array("message"=> "This is a test message"); 
$message_status = send_notification($tokens,$message);
echo $message_status; ***//Trouble here. it just prints out "To" whenever i hit the php script***

?>
```

Now whenever i hit the script, the response just returns

```
To
```

and nothing else.. and No notification is delivered as well. Unable to figure out the issue. Requesting your guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to use 'to' instead of 'registration_ids'**

Here is body data saved in postman history[i don't remember whether it works or not]:

```
{ "data": {
"score": "5x1",
"time": "15:10" }, "to" : "token_id"}
```

Check this script: If you want to do topic messaging

```
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
                $topic = "topic_name";
                $fields = array(
                    "to"                => "/topics/".$topic,
                    "data"              => $message,
                    "time_to_live"      => 30,
                    "delay_while_idle"  => true
                );

                $auth_key = "auth_key";

                $headers = array(
                    "Authorization: key=".$auth_key,
                    "Content-Type: application/json"
                );

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Hope that help

Comment: Thanks.much. But no luck changing the value from registration_ids to "To". I tried using your method and postman gives me Field "data" must be a JSON array:

Comment: that means there is problem in creting json

Comment: Apologies, Can you help me out here please

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks much...:)  i just modified your code to send it to a single recipient :)

Comment: if you want to add more info about the fix you can add in the answer or question

Comment: I have now :) Thanks much again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much @Shubham for the solution.

Guys please use @Shubham's code for sending notifications to "Topics'

I have modified his code a bit to address Single recipient messaging. Here it goes

```
<?php

$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
                $val = "<your recipient id>";
                $message = array("message" => "This is a test message from server");
                $fields = array(
                    "to"                => $val,
                    "data"              => $message,
                    "time_to_live"      => 30,
                    "delay_while_idle"  => true
                );

                $auth_key = "<Your auth key>";

                $headers = array(
                    "Authorization: key=".$auth_key,"Content-Type: application/json"
                    );

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
                $result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

> to  - Single recipient
>   registration_ids -  multicast messages (Many recipients - should be in array)

This may not be the ideal solution from my end but it definitely works :)