# FCM server error in Android

Tags: php, android

When we try to send notification data from PHP server to Android using FCM then we get error `MismatchSenderId`.

The error log is:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 6512073968181820231,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "MismatchSenderId"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please provide me help to find solution of that, thanks in advance.

Comment: MismatchSender ID usually occurs when the server key you are using is incorrect. it will be something like AIzaSyDiTEVq4Li1pj7IyrXXXXXXX-49-KVY. Please ensure that you have the right package name and SHA1 for generating the server key

Comment: Hello Sriram i have right sha1 and package name for server key when i send from FCM server from notification section its working.But when it try from php or try from postman its shoing error.

Comment: Please check if this link helps for push notification using php, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540782/android-push-notification-through-firebase-server-side/38541988#38541988

Comment: k Sriram i will check it and respond you soon thanks.

Comment: Hello Sriram its not working sending same error mismatched senderId.

Comment: Can you post your php code here please? and please check this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274351/php-gcm-error-message-mismatchsenderid

Comment: Hello i got error and its work fine actually in FCM the format of device token is different from GCM.

Comment: In GCM Device token format is-->(APA91bHVeLSLkaV3PPjDJSrz1-ErrOhjtIYFO3Vwp4zqeuoxoE_fnRjrmCJGRPC9xQCZyFpMhcuBHsIKl09NUPBoq0_OTeWhMFypYgjaN4Tyr2i5vjXEDnY6TRmHWxELS_XYKbYaRypl)       but In FCM device token format is-->(pUlJ5jKZk:APA91bHVeLSLkaV3PPjDJSrz1-ErrOhjtIYFO3Vwp4zqeuoxoE_fnRjrmCJGRPC9xQCZyFpMhcuBHsIKl09NUPBoq0_OTeWhMFypYgjaN4Tyr2i5vjXEDnY6TRmHWxELS_XYKbYaRypl).